# Запись данных в переменную

Tags: python, python-2.x

Хочу записать информацию в переменную, а затем сохранить в файл.

Есть код:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()
DRIVE_TYPES = {
  0 : "Unknown",
  1 : "No Root Directory",
  2 : "Removable Disk",
  3 : "Local Disk",
  4 : "Network Drive",
  5 : "Compact Disc",
  6 : "RAM Disk"
}

for drive in c.Win32_LogicalDisk ():
  print drive.Caption, DRIVE_TYPES[drive.DriveType]
```

который при запуске печатает

```
C: Local Disk
D: Local Disk
E: Compact Disc
F: Compact Disc
G: Compact Disc
```

Все нормально. Но когда я записываю информацию в переменную и потом пытаюсь вывести на экран информацию из неё, то получается такая вот штука `(u'G:', 'Compact Disc')` и все.
Не пойму в чем дело. То что выводит

```
C: Local Disk
D: Local Disk
E: Compact Disc
F: Compact Disc
G: Compact Disc
```

это же не список, не словарь, не строка.

Comment: @Abyx, ааааа.... понял, спасибо! буду читать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что при присваивании запятая распознаётся как конструктор кортежа (tuple). Если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь выполнить следующее выражение:

```
value = drive.Caption, DRIVE_TYPES[drive.DriveType]
```

Это выражение эквивалентно

```
value = (drive.Caption, DRIVE_TYPES[drive.DriveType])
```

Кортеж можно примерно считать неизменяемым списком. Выводится на экран он как раз в том формате, в котором вы указали.

Вы получаете иное представление при печати, так как запятая у оператора `print` не является конструктором кортежа, а просто разделяет аргументы оператора. Значения, переданные в оператор `print` преобразуются в строковое представление и разделяются пробелами, именно поэтому вы видите удобное для вас представление.

Если вы хотите получить строку вида `C: Local Disk`, то для этого можно воспользоваться форматирующим методом строки:

```
value = u'{} {}'.format(drive.Caption, DRIVE_TYPES[drive.DriveType])
print value    #  C: Local Disk
```

Comment: ,от Души Спасибо большое !!! подскажи пожалуйста где взять так скажем полную информацию по работе с Python или какие нибудь справочники ... потому что интернет дает поверхностную информацию(за редким исключением) в инете была информация что из себя представляет КОРТЕЖ но ни как с ним работать конкретно . заранее спасибо !

Comment: такая незадача - если print выполняется в теле то все работает но если попытаться выполнить print вне тела то печатает только  одну строку G: Compact Disc. и записывает в файл  тоже только одну строку --- G: Compact Disc

Comment: @Игорь если вы имеете в виду тело цикла, то это логично -- print исполняется столько же раз, сколько раз происходит итерация. Если вам нужно сохранить несколько значений, используйте список. Насчёт литературы -- есть довольно много книг по Python ([en](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonBooks), [ru](https://wiki.python.org/moin/RussianPythonBooks)), есть несколько курсов ([coursera](https://www.coursera.org/), [stepic (на русском)](https://stepic.org/)). Если есть знание английского на уровне чтения, то исследуйте https://www.python.org/.

Comment: Огромное спасибо !!!